# MySQL update query join and join left

Tags: php, mysql

I know basics of mysql and need help in updating query where select query is this:

```
SELECT f.FinalAmount,f.ActualAmount,fh.ActualPaid,p.Name package,f.FromDate,f.ToDate 
from customers c 
join fees f on f.CustomerID = c.ID 
join packages p on p.ID=f.PackageID 
left join fees_history fh on f.ID = fh.ReferenceID  
where c.ID='108239' and c.branch='664'
```

I want to update `f.FromDate` but know know How to do that because the SELECT statement need join query.

Comment: Review Multiple-table syntax: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html

Answer (score 1):

Directly:

```
UPDATE 

       customers c 
join fees f on f.CustomerID = c.ID 
join packages p on p.ID=f.PackageID 
left join fees_history fh on f.ID = fh.ReferenceID  

SET f.FromDate = ???

where c.ID='108239' and c.branch='664'
```

PS. `left join fees_history fh on f.ID = fh.ReferenceID` does not affect the update and must be removed.

Comment: A left join in an update is a strange thing to behold

Comment: @Strawberry Yes... excluding the choice when the value for updating is taken from left-joined table. Like `SET f.FromDate = COALESCE(fh.FromDate, f.FromDate )`.

Comment: Even then, I'd probably just execute two updates

Comment: @Strawberry ??? two updates? I don't understand what do you mean... PS. The only visible improvement in described case (the value for updating is taken from `fees_history`) is to move all 3 conditions by `customers` table to WHERE EXISTS.